# Closing Child window on success response from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have a OAuth process where the main window will open up a child window so the user can sign in through OAuth. 
If user provides successful credentials, the child window will pass a token to my server and the server will return something like { code: 200, message: success } to the child window.

How can I close this child window automatically upon success?

Comment: Call `window.close()`???

Comment: How would I know from the parent window that the child has the success code though? 
I have var child = window.open('url'). Would a value on child somehow change when it gets a success response?

Comment: I would say why are you using window.open() to communicate and not an XMLHttpRequest. Using a window is asking for problems with pop up blockers. Only way to know would be for the child window to pass data back to the parent, figured you were already doing that.

Comment: I need window.open() for the oAuth verification by user. This child window is where the user will provide username/pass so I can get the aToken to access Dropbox.